# It's showing an error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {street, suite, city, zipcode, geo})."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state

After successful fetch of users data from json placeholder api using React Hooks System , I am not able to show the records inside table. It shows an error
[see the attached image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxeSX.png)

You can checkout the code on this link : [check out the code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-operations-using-react-hooks-i2rdt?file=/src/components/TableRecords.js)

Please let me know where i am doing a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `address` is an object. And you are trying to render an object in the table cell.

Please use the correct key or stringify the object to render it.

```
<td>{JSON.stringify(address)}</td>
```

Also, next time please add your code on the question body and the steps that you have tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering `address` as if it were a string or React component:

```
<td>{address}</td>
```

However, it is in fact an object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

You'll need to either make a component that renders an `address` or translate it to a string before rendering.